# Getting "Method Not Allowed" error when POST /actuator/bus-refresh in Spring Cloud Bus

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-bus

I'm using Spring Cloud Bus and RabbitMQ to broadcast configuration changes to some microservices, but when I hit POST request to http://localhost:8888/actuator/bus-refresh I'm getting an error "Method Not Allowed", as below:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 
Allow: GET
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2020 05:53:36 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "timestamp": "2020-03-26T05:53:36.872+0000",
  "status": 405,
  "error": "Method Not Allowed",
  "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
  "path": "/actuator/bus-refresh"
}
```

Here is my application.yml file

```
server.port: 8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri: E:/Work/git/microservices-poc-using-spring-cloud/config-repo
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: bus-refresh,refresh
```

But when I change the exposure property to allow all endpoints, I got a success response and changes broadcasted successfully to my microservice.

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

And the response is succeeded.

```
HTTP/1.1 204 
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2020 05:42:32 GMT
Connection: close
```

My pom.xml is simple

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sabahallah.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-server</name>
    <description>Microservices Config Server</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for broadcasting configuration changes -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ************************* -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and only one java file

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: /bus-refresh does not support post. /monitor accepts posts and tries to figure out what services to refresh based on headers or content from vcs webhooks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below to application.properties solved it for me.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

or to be specific you can add support to the desired endpoint

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=busrefresh
```

note that in older versions it's "bus-refresh"

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the same error And solved it by changing the Spring cloud version.
Initially i used <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>

Now i have changed version to Greenwich.SR1,
<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>